# Why are some random() functions deemed "not secure?"

Tags: random

I've heard people being warned all over the place not to rely on a language's `random()` function to generate a random number or string sequence "for security reasons." Java even has a `SecureRandom` class. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When people talk about predicting the output of a random number generator, they don't even need to get the actual "next number". Even something subtle like noticing that the random numbers aren't evenly distributed, or that they never produce the same number twice in a row, or that "bit 5 is always set", can go a long way towards turning an attack based on guessing a "random" number from taking years, to taking days.

There is a tradeoff, generally, too. Without specific hardware to do it, generating large quantities of random numbers quickly can be really hard, since there isn't enough "randomness" available to the computer so it has to fake it.

If you're not using the randomness for security (cryptography, passwords, etc), but instead for things like simulations or numerical work, then it doesn't matter too much if they're predictable, only that they're statistically random.

Comment: So something like `sha256(str(random.randomint() * 1000000000)).hexdigest()` is just asking for a security threat? Would this be mitigated by generating a random string salt and including it in the hash input?

Comment: I'm not good enough at crypto to really say confidently, but I think it'd depend on how the particular implementation is generating the random numbers. (I think the default python one is deterministic, for example). Salts are useful for making it harder for people to guess the input, given the hashed output, but that's a little different from how good the random number is in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every random number generator is 'pseudo random' in that it uses a table of random numbers or a predictable formula. A seed is sometimes used to "start" the random sequence at a specific point, e.g. seedRandom(timer).

This was especially prevalent in the days of BAsIC programming, because it's random number generator always started at exactly the same sequence of numbers, making it unusable for any kind of GUID generation.

Back in the day, the Z-80 microprocessor had a truly random number generator, although it was only a number between 0 and 127. It used a processor cycle function and was unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-random numbers that can be determined in advance can lead to security holes that are vulnerable to a [random number generator attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator_attack).

Answer (score 0):

Predictability of a random number is a big issue. Most "random" functions derive their value from time. Given the right set of conditions you could end up with two "random" numbers of a large value that are the same.

In windows .NET world CPRNG (Cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator) can be found in  System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator through underlying win32 APIs
In Linux there is a random "device"